# VBA Check if File Exists on Sharepoint Site

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, office365

After some searching I cant find a solution to my issue. I have multiple files that are saved to a sharepoint site with variable names each month.  I have the files saving correctly with the variable name.  I used the "filename" dim as the path for saving so I know that works.

What i am trying to do is have vba check to see if that name is already exists on the sharepoint site to prevent a user from overwritting existing files.  Below is the code I put together from browsing around on the web.  Using F8 to run the vba code line by line, I get error:

> Bad file name or number

Any thoughts to get this to run correctly?

```
    sub test()
    Dim filename As String ''''filename is the sharepoint site and file name
    DirFile = filename
    If Len(Dir(filename)) = 0 Then
    Else
    MsgBox "File already exists on sharepoint site"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to convert the file's SharePoint URL to a valid folder path.

Comment: Can you provide some insight how to do this?  trying not to map Sharepoint as a network drive on each users computer.

Comment: If you add an example address to your question, I'll have a go. Obviously, remove/change the main site address.

Comment: check out this gist, which converts a sharepoint url to a local file if it exits: https://gist.github.com/Alex-ley/a8b4a27919ddf937080d9b5be2ff7968 - note you can only do what you are trying to do (I believe) if the file is synced locally. That is what this gist is going to help with - fining the local sync folder etc.